# Maven Central vs Other Repos?

Tags: maven, redhat, maven-central

On the maven centrral, I can see several other Repositories available for some of the libraries. For example - Apache Common BeanUtils is available in Central, Redhat GA, JBoss 3rd-party etc. The library name changes as well. For example, Maven CCentral has versions like 1.9.4, however Redhat GA has versions like - 1.9.3.redhat-1.

Click on this URI to see the details.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils

My question is - What is the difference between Repo marked as Central and "Redhat GA"?

Attaching an image of :Maven GA; repo as well here. [image]

Comment: Just to make sure: You know that mvnrepository is _not_ MavenCentral?

Comment: I can acknowledge the comment of JF Meier.

Comment: @JFMeier, thanks for clarifying. Yes. I understand that central and "redhat" are two separate Repos. Context of my question is more around   - how safe is to use version of a library from other Repos (for example-Redhat in this case) than Central? Or what are the scenarios when an Enterprise application should use a library from other Repos than Maven Central?

Comment: Actually, I recently also wondered why redhat "rebuild" a lot of commonly available libraries with their own version numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Re:

*My question is - What is the difference between Repo marked as Central and "Redhat GA"?*

From here: https://access.redhat.com/maven-repository

**"Redhat GA" is the general availability JBoss Enterprise Maven Repository.**

And the page also mentions:

> Artifacts in the repository do not receive automated security patches as Maven requires that artifacts be immutable. As a result, artifacts that are missing patches for **known security flaws** will remain in the repository to avoid breaking builds that depend on them. **Patched artifacts have their version number incremented.**

If you checkout the README at the repository: https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/README.md

> This archive contains Maven repository artifacts for JBoss WFK 2.  This is meant
> to be used as additional Maven repository in development environment with
> JBoss EAP 6 Maven repository.

So it seems **Redhat GA versions are patched versions of Maven Central artifacts**, specifically to support JBoss WFK.

My guess is that the patches correct security flaws in the base Maven Central artifact.

---

Re:

*For example, Maven CCentral has versions like 1.9.4, however Redhat GA has versions like - 1.9.3.redhat-1.*

For this example, **my guess is that 1.9.3.redhat-1 is a security patched version of 1.9.3 from Maven Central**.

---

Re: (comment above)

*how safe is to use version of a library from other Repos (for example-Redhat in this case) than Central? Or what are the scenarios when an Enterprise application should use a library from other Repos than Maven Central?*

If you need a security-hardened version of a specific Maven Central version, but you can't upgrade to a later version from Maven Central (for any reason: risk, incompatibilities, one does not exist, etc) - the Red Hat version might be a solution.

As to whether it's safe, it's up to whether you trust RedHat vs Maven vs any other organization providing open source.